# Sending message via Websocket in Spark Java

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm new in Java Spark framework and need to implement websocket via spark.

- As i known in Spring have `MessageTemplate` to sending message via websocket to the any client connections.
- So, any object or mechanism to sending message via websocket like `MessageTemplate` in Spring framework?